# Python Increment Int variable in a String

Tags: python

I can't seem to make a variable that prints out a line of text and next to it a variable containing an integer that increments each time the for loop is executed. This is my code:

```
id = 1
for x in range(0, 4):
 studentID = 'Bart: ' + `id`
 print(studentID)
 id += 1
```

The loop executes four times but it just prints out

```
Bart: 1
Bart: 1
Bart: 1
Bart: 1
```

for four times it doesn't increment the `id` integer

Comment: This works for me; what version of Python are you using?

Comment: What version are you using? It works for me on 2.7

Comment: I'm using pycharm I think 4

Comment: @BartLorenzo You are using Python4? Python 3.5 is the latest version available

Comment: @BartLorenzo Are you using the exact indentation as in the question?

Comment: Sorry I'm new to python didn't know the latest version , and yes

Comment: @Adalee do **not** fix indentation in questions. Many Python problems can be traced to incorrect indentation, and your attempts at helping would just hide the problem. Code formatting changes are not a valid edit reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
id = 1
for x in range(1, 4):
    studentID = "Bart: {}".format(id)
    print(studentID)
    id += 1
```

But, why are you incrementing id inside a for loop? Why not just use the for loop?

Edit:
Also, you can use `print("Bart: ", id)`. And, if you want them all on the same line as you show, you can use either of these:

```
 print("Bart: ", id, end="")
```

or

```
sys.stdout.write("Bart: ") 
sys.stdout.write(str(id))
sys.stdout.write(" ")
```

You will need `import sys` at the top of your file.

These are Python 3+ solutions.

Comment: Wouldn't this give you only three iterations, since range excludes the right border?

Comment: OMG wow it was just a simple syntax error instead of using "," I was using the "+" symbol thank you

Comment: Please use proper indentation. It should be 4 spaces, not 1.

Comment: I fixed the indentation.

Answer (score 1):

Your posted code works. I can only assume that you accidentally fixed it when posting here, and that your actual code had the increment outside the loop:

```
id = 1
for x in range(0, 4):
    studentID = 'Bart: ' + `id`
    print(studentID)
id += 1
```

That really *does* print four times "1", obviously. I note that someone else indented your code to the proper four spaces, and your original code only had a one space indent, making it less clear to see when you're missing one.